# How do I access arrays of array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, join, multidimensional-array, perl-data-structures

Hi I have a array as myarray. I would like to make a list as '1 2 3' which is joining the first subarray. My string is printing the memory location I suppose instead of list. any help will be appreciated.

```
@myarray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
for (my $i=0; $i < @myarray; $i++) {
my @firstarray = $myarray[$i];
my $mystring = join("", @firstarray);
print "My string ".$mystring . ". "\n";
}
```

Comment: Learn about Perl references and dereferencing. Contrary to popular belief, they're almost totally unlike C-style pointers, and you are doing some strange things with them in your example. The following Perl tutorial gives the most concise treatment of the subject I know: http://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html

Comment: `use warnings;` -- that would have alerted you to your strange initialization for `@myarray`

Comment: for references I prefer the core document [perldoc perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut). It makes references much more understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to dereference the inner array reference by `@{ ... }`. Also, do not use `[...]` for the top structure - use normal parentheses (square brackets create an array reference, not an array). There was also a problem with the concatenation on your `print` line:

```
@myarray = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] );
for (my $i=0; $i < @myarray; $i++) {
    my @firstarray = @{ $myarray[$i] };
    my $mystring = join("", @firstarray);
    print "My string " . $mystring . ".\n";
}
```

Comment: @ikegami: I just tried to stay as close as possible to the original code.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `Data::Dumper` module, that way, that will help you to know how to parse your data structure :

```
print Dumper \@myarray; # force passing array as ref
$VAR1 = [
          [
            [
              1,
              2,
              3
            ],
            [
              4,
              5,
              6
            ],
            [
              7,
              8,
              9
            ]
          ]
        ];
```

But using the `@` [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) (array) to store an *ARRAY ref* is strange, a `$` sigil (scalar) is used most of the times for that purpose. (a *reference* is like a `C` pointer : an address to a memory cell. So its' a simple string, no need something else than a scalar to store it)

Then, you need to *de-reference* with the `->` operator.

Ex :

```
$ perlconsole
Perl Console 0.4

Perl> my $arrayref = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

Perl> print join "\n", @{ $arrayref->[2] }
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually have an array of array of array.

- The outer array has one element, a reference to an array.
  `$myarray[0]`
- That referenced array has three elements, each a reference to an array.
  `$myarray[0][0..2]`
- Each of those referenced arrays have three elements, three numbers.
  `$myarray[0][0..2][0..2]`

You want

```
my @aoa = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]);
   ^       ^       ^       ^
   |        \------+------/
   |            3 inner
1 outer

$aoa[$i][$j]

for my $inner (@aoa) {
   print(join(', ', @$inner), "\n");
}
```

or

```
my $aoa = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
          ^^       ^       ^
          | \------+------/
          |      3 inner
       1 outer

$aoa->[$i][$j]

for my $inner (@$aoa) {
   print(join(', ', @$inner), "\n");
}
```

Comment: why is it an "array of array of array"?  i see an outer array or three inner single-dimensional arrays

Comment: @amphibient, Because you have 3 arrays referenced by elements of one array referenced by elements of one array. That's 5 arrays, not 4. As I showed, count the `my @` and the `[]`. Remember that `[...]` is basically `do { my @a = (...); \@a }`.

Comment: but if you have 3 inner and one outer, that is 4 arrays, no?  besides, i would just look at it as a simple `AoA [3][3]`

Comment: @amphibient, Yes, if you had 3 inner and one outer, that would be 4. Since he has 5 (one created with `my` and 4 created with `[]`), he doesn't have 3 inner and one outer. This can also bee seen with `Dumper(\@myarray)`.

Comment: ah, OK -- so you are saying that, the way he declares it, he has 5, whereas he is supposed to correctly have 4

Comment: @amphibient, Yup. He's got an AoAoA when he wants an AoA.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change how you initialize your array so that `()` is used for the outer array bounds and `[]` for the inner arrays, which means that they are declared as references that will later need to be cast into their native array format for processing (`my @subarray = @{$myarray[$i]};`)

```
my @myarray = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]);

for (my $i=0; $i < @myarray; $i++) 
{
    my @subarray = @{$myarray[$i]};
    my $subarrayStr = join("", @subarray);
    print $i.". Subarray Str = ".$subarrayStr."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
printf "My string %s\n", join(" ", @{$myarray->[0]});
```

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` returns a reference to the list of lists, not a list.

Change the `@` into `$` , to make `$myarray` a variable.

`@{$myarray->[0]}` will dereference the first sublist and return you the list you can use.

To print all three lists:

```
$myarray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
map{printf "My string %s\n", join(" ",@{$_})} @{$myarray};
```