# Querying multiple times in Oracle using perl returns only the first query

Tags: database, oracle, perl, dbi, data-dumper

Note: I have corrected the variable differences and it does print the query from the first set but it returns nothing from the second set. If I use the second set only it works.

In the code below, I have some_array which is array of array the array contains text like name. So 
    @some_array= ([sam, jon, july],[Mike, Han,Tommy],[angie, sita, lanny]); 
Now when I querying the list like 'sam jon july' first and 'mike han tommy' . Only the execute return the result from the first list others is undef. I don't know why any help will be appreciated.

```
my $pointer;
my $db = $db->prepare_cached("
        begin
                :pointer := myFun(:A1);
        end;
                ") or die "Couldn't prepare stat: " . $db->errstr;
$db->bind_param_inout(":pointer",\$pointer,0,{ ora_type => ORA_RSET });

for (my $i=0; $i < @some_array ; $i++) {
        my @firstarray = @{$some_array[$i]};
        my $sql = lc(join(" ", @firstarray));
        print "<pre>$sql</pre>\n";
        $db->bind_param(":A1",$sql);
        $db->execute();
        print "<pre>".Dumper($db->execute())."</pre>\n";
 }
```

Comment: This can't possibly be your real code, can it? Why are `@sql` and `$sql` initialized but not used, while `@query` and `$query` are used but not initialized? What are `$db`, `$dbh`, and `$sdh` and why does it seem like they are used so inconsistently? In the future, please make a better effort to post code that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: I am sorry for the variable differences, I have corrected it. Also it does prints the result but for the first set only second set returns undef. If I use the second set as first then it will return second set only. So the problem is its returning the first set only.

Answer (score 2):

Just like everyone told you on [the last question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486604/how-do-i-access-arrays-of-array-in-perl), initialize your array with parentheses, not nested brackets.

```
@some_array= ([sam, jon, july],[Mike, Han,Tommy],[angie, sita, lanny])
```

not

```
@some_array= [[sam, jon, july],[Mike, Han,Tommy],[angie, sita, lanny]]
```

You would also benefit tremendously from including

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of all of your programs. That would catch the strange way you are trying to initialize `@some_array`, and it would catch your inconsistent usage of `@sql` and `@query`. **update** and `$sdh` and `$db` and `$dbh`.

Comment: I have edited as you said and also used strict and warnings but no help.